# how to force spring boot to set autowired fields in unit tests

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, javabeans, autowired

I'm developing a spring boot application. I tried to develop some UNIT TESTs. 
Unit tests must run without starting app in container, must be so fast that can be run without a lot of time.
Imagine I had a class name `ApplicationService` as follows:

```
@Service
public class ApplicationService {

     @Autowired
     private ApplicationRepository applicationRepository;


     @Autowired
     private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

     ///............
}
```

and below test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(MockitoTestExecutionListener.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class CreateApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    ApplicationService applicationService;

    @Mock
    private ApplicationRepository applicationRepository;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void createApplication() {
        CreateApplicationDTO dto = new CreateApplicationDTO("some info");
        given(this.applicationService.createApplication(dto)).willReturn(null);
        ApplicationResultDTO application = applicationService.createApplication(dto);
        assertThat(application, is(someValue));
    }
}
```

although mocking is correct and works (in this sample `ApplicationService.applicationRepository` is mocked) but other AutoWired fields (in this sample `ApplicationService.passwordEncoder`) remain null.

how to config tests to apply default instances (from beans) to other fields?

Answer (score 0):

Add `PasswordEncoder` to test class annotated `@Spy` `@Autowired` so it can be used inside mocked `ApplicationService`

```
@Spy
@Autowired
private  PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

Comment: this does not work and creates error "Mockito cannot mock this class: interface .....ApplicationRepository. Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes." being "mockito-core" in dependencies make this error, even not using @Spy

Comment: @HomayounBehzadian you should `Spy` the relevant PasswordEncoder implementation you use

Comment: what you mean? apply @Spy on class of `PasswordEncoder`? or on field of type `PasswordEncoder`?

Comment: @HomayounBehzadian Spy on field inside Test class

Comment: using `@Spy` on fields in test class in equal to using `@Mock`. I just tested and both fields set to mocked objects. I need for second field to be set to actual value

Comment: @User72949600 also my real class has a lot of this fields + their nested fields. so this method does not work

Answer (score 0):

For UNIT TESTS you don't need the `SpringRunner` (or `SpringExtension`). They are more suitable for integration tests. They are also very slow. The purpose of a unit test is to test the isolated class. Mockito is therefor more suitable for this task.

Normally, I would implement it differently. Instead of `@Autowired` fields I suggest to use a `@Inject` on a constructor, like this:

```java
@Service
public class ApplicationService {

     private ApplicationRepository applicationRepository;

     private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

     @Inject
     public ApplicationService(ApplicationRepository applicationRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
         this.applicationRepository = applicationRepository;
         this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
     }

     ///............
}
```

Now you have a class with a constructor that you can use. You don't need any dependency injection.

The test class can be like this:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) //junit5, but junit4 is also possible
public class ApplicationServiceTest {

     @Mock
     private ApplicationRepository applicationRepository;

     @Mock
     private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

     @InjectMocks
     private ApplicationService sut; //ServiceUnderTest

     // Now write your tests
}
```

Comment: I do not wan to mock all dependencies because only some of them are used in specific test and also there are a lot of dependency (more that 30), some of them must not mocked and each of dependencies may has inner services

Comment: Especially because of that you need to mock the dependencies. You want to test 1 Class only! Not the dependent classes. Mock every dependency and you control all functionality without needing to control sub dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the value of passwordEncoder from your test case itself using `doReturn().when();`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(MockitoTestExecutionListener.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class CreateApplicationTest {

@Autowired
@InjectMocks
ApplicationService applicationService;

@Mock
private ApplicationRepository applicationRepository;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void createApplication() {

    `doReturn("value of passwordEncoder").
         when(applicationService).getPasswordEncoder();`

    CreateApplicationDTO dto = new CreateApplicationDTO("some info");
    given(this.applicationService.createApplication(dto)).willReturn(null);
    ApplicationResultDTO application = applicationService.createApplication(dto);
    assertThat(application, is(someValue));
}
```

}